# Assign table values to multiple variables using a single SELECT statement and CASE?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, case

I'm trying to assign values contained in a lookup table to multiple variables by using a single SELECT having multiple CASE statements.

The table is a lookup table with two columns like so:

```
[GreekAlphabetastic]

  SystemID    Descriptor
  --------    ----------
  1           Alpha
  2           Beta
  3           Epsilon
```

This is my syntax:

```
SELECT 

    @VariableTheFirst = 
        CASE
            WHEN myField = 'Alpha' THEN tbl.SystemID
        END,

    @VariableTheSecond = 
        CASE
            WHEN myField = 'Beta' THEN tbl.SystemID
        END,

    @VariableTheThird = 
        CASE
            WHEN myField = 'Epsilon' THEN tbl.SystemID
        END

FROM GreekAlphabetastic tbl
```

However, when I check the variables after this statement executes, I expected each to be assigned the appropriate value, but instead only the *last* has a value assigned.

```
SELECT 
    @VariableTheFirst AS First, 
    @VariableTheSecond AS Second, 
    @VariableTheThird AS Third

Results:

    First    Second    Third
    NULL     NULL      3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first 2 variables are being reset to null after being assigned. i.e. when it hits the Epsilon record, the first 2 variables are being assigned to null as there is nothing to prevent that in the CASE statement.

So, try this:

```
SELECT     
    @VariableTheFirst = 
        CASE
            WHEN Descriptor = 'Alpha' THEN tbl.SystemID
            ELSE @VariableTheFirst
        END,

    @VariableTheSecond = 
        CASE
            WHEN Descriptor = 'Beta' THEN tbl.SystemID
            ELSE @VariableTheSecond
        END,

    @VariableTheThird = 
        CASE
            WHEN Descriptor = 'Epsilon' THEN tbl.SystemID
            ELSE @VariableTheThird
        END
FROM GreekAlphabetastic tbl
```

Comment: this works, but if the table is large three SELECTs using a WHERE (and an index) will be faster.

Comment: @AdaTheDev: Thanks, I understand now what went wrong! :)
@KM: Fortunately this is just a lookup table with only a handful of records, it won't have more than a few additional records added to it in the near future, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

when making assignments to local variables from a SELECT, only the last row processed will affect the variables. for the third row, the `CASE myField = 'Alpha'` and `CASE myField = 'Beta'` are false and the variables are set to NULL.  The `CASE myField = 'Epsilon'` is true and @VariableTheThird is assigned 3.

if you want this to work do this:

```
SELECT @VariableTheFirst = tbl.SystemID WHERE myField = 'Alpha'
SELECT @VariableTheSecond = tbl.SystemID WHERE myField = 'Beta'
SELECT @VariableTheThird = tbl.SystemID WHERE myField = 'Epsilon'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     
        CASE
            WHEN Descriptor = 'Alpha' THEN @VariableTheFirst = isnull(@VariableTheFirst,tbl.SystemID)
            WHEN Descriptor = 'Beta' THEN @VariableTheSecond = isnull(@VariableTheSecond,tbl.SystemID)
            WHEN Descriptor = 'Epsilon' THEN @VariableTheThird = isnull(@VariableTheThird,tbl.SystemID)
        END
FROM GreekAlphabetastic tbl
```

Comment: Statements (like an assignment) are not allowed after THEN, only expressions are allowed.